# Quarto Website, Irresolvable Merge Conflict

Tags: git, rstudio, quarto

So, I did something quite dumb and when updating my Quarto website hosted on Github I checked the 'amend previous commit' box:

[image]

Because of things I don't quite understand, this then resulted in irreconcilable differences between the local and hosted versions of my page such that I now have these peppered all over my website:

[image]

The really vexing thing about this is that the offending strings appear nowhere in the .qmd documents that generate in the pages (though they do appear in .html documents within a separate docs/ folder).

This brings me to my two questions. First, what would be the 'proper' way to solve this? (I'm aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-a-git-repository), but when I run `git mergetool` in the terminal I get `No files need merging`).

Second, assuming the 'proper' way is extremely tedious, what would be a 'nuclear' option where I just say, "Listen, my local files render just as I'd like them to, so can we scrap the inconsistencies and just go with that?"

Many thanks beforehand.

**Links**: [Here](https://jdollman.github.io/home/posts/2024-01-31-sentiments-dictionaries/)'s the webpage,
[here](https://github.com/jdollman/home/blob/main/posts/2024-01-31-sentiments-dictionaries/index.qmd)'s the .qmd file in my github repository, and [here](https://github.com/jdollman/home/blob/main/docs/posts/2024-01-31-sentiments-dictionaries/index.html)'s the .html file where the merge conflicts are visible.